# Build compound literal with derived class

Tags: c++

I don't understand the behaviour in 'Case 5' (see Main):

1. Why is there a copy constructor called ?
2. Why does Deriv copy constructor isn't called ?
3. Is 'Base *b' corrupted in foo ?

Classes/Functions/Main

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    void        hello(void) {
        std::cout << "this=" << (void*)this << std::endl; }

    Base() : i(42) {
        std::cout << "Base  CTOR ";
        this->hello(); }

    ~Base() {
        std::cout << "Base  DTOR ";
        this->hello(); }

    Base(Base const &src) : i(43) {
        std::cout << "Base  CCPY ";
        this->hello(); }

    Base        &operator=(Base const &rhs) = delete;

    int     i;

};

struct Deriv : public Base
{
    void        hello(void) {
        std::cout << "this=" << (void*)this << std::endl; }

    Deriv() : Base(), j(84) {
        std::cout << "Deriv CTOR ";
        this->hello(); }

    ~Deriv() {
        std::cout << "Deriv DTOR ";
        this->hello(); }

    Deriv(Deriv const &src) : Base(src),j(85) {
        std::cout << "Deriv CCPY ";
        this->hello(); }

    Deriv       &operator=(Deriv const &rhs) = delete;

    int     j;
};

void        foo(Base *b)
{
    std::cout << "        foo b = " << (void*)b
              << std::endl;
    return ;
}
void        bar(Base const &b)
{
    std::cout << "        foo b = " << (void*)&b
              << std::endl;
    return ;
}

int                         main(void)
{
    bar(Base());             // Case 1 (Ok)
    std::cout << std::endl;
    foo((Base[]){Base()});   // Case 2 (Same as Case 4)

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    bar(Deriv());            // Case 3 (Ok)
    std::cout << std::endl;
    foo((Deriv[]){Deriv()}); // Case 4 (Same as Case 3)

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    foo((Base[]){Deriv()});  // Case 5 (Partial copy, bad bad bad ?)
    return (0);
}
```

Output

```
Base  CTOR this=0x7fff5d477818
        foo b = 0x7fff5d477818
Base  DTOR this=0x7fff5d477818

Base  CTOR this=0x7fff5d477808
        foo b = 0x7fff5d477808
Base  DTOR this=0x7fff5d477808


Base  CTOR this=0x7fff5d4777f8
Deriv CTOR this=0x7fff5d4777f8
        foo b = 0x7fff5d4777f8
Deriv DTOR this=0x7fff5d4777f8
Base  DTOR this=0x7fff5d4777f8

Base  CTOR this=0x7fff5d477880
Deriv CTOR this=0x7fff5d477880
        foo b = 0x7fff5d477880
Deriv DTOR this=0x7fff5d477880
Base  DTOR this=0x7fff5d477880


Base  CTOR this=0x7fff5d4777d8
Deriv CTOR this=0x7fff5d4777d8
Base  CCPY this=0x7fff5d4777e8
        foo b = 0x7fff5d4777e8
Base  DTOR this=0x7fff5d4777e8
Deriv DTOR this=0x7fff5d4777d8
Base  DTOR this=0x7fff5d4777d8
```

Compiler

```
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Compound literals are not standard C++. Derived copy constructor isn't called because you are slicing.

Comment: Please don’t take this personally but your formatting is absolutely atrocious, because it appears to lack consistency and goes against established norms. Put the closing braces on a new line. Remove the extraneous spaces between type and object/function name. Remove unnecessary `return` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of a class type as in `Base[]` is an array of elements of the exact type `Base`. Since the elements are actually placed in the array memory, there is no space to contain a different actual type.

If you provide matching elements, they are placed in the array. On the other hand, if you provide different types, the compiler checks for a way to convert from the provided type to `Base`. The copy constructor of `Base` is a valid way to convert the `Deriv` object.

If you want to store derived types in an array, you need to store them by reference (pointer). This allows to allocate a correct array size regardless of the element size.